# add link to list of post terms

Tags: php, wordpress, function, categories

I need to change the function below so that it outputs a list if links rather than a string. So the resulting html i need is `<a href="#">term</a>`.

```
function my_post_terms() {

// Get an array of all taxonomies for this post
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( '', 'names' );

// Are there any taxonomies to get terms from?
if ( $taxonomies ) {    

    // Call the wp_get_post_terms function to retrieve all terms. It accepts an array of taxonomies as argument. 
    $arr_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), array_values( $taxonomies ) , array( "fields" => "names" ) );

    // Convert the terms array to a string
    $terms = implode( ' ',$arr_terms );

    // Get out of here
    return $terms;
}
}
```

Comment: A simple `foreach` should do the trick.

Comment: where would you write this within the function?

Answer (score 0):

Try as flowing code ..

```
function my_post_terms() {

// Get an array of all taxonomies for this post
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( '', 'names' );

// Are there any taxonomies to get terms from?
if ( $taxonomies ) {    

    // Call the wp_get_post_terms function to retrieve all terms. It accepts an array of taxonomies as argument. 
    $arr_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), array_values( $taxonomies ) , array( "fields" => "names" ) );

    // Convert the terms array to a string
    $terms = implode( ' ',$arr_terms );

    // Get out of here

  if (!filter_var($terms , FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === false) {
       echo "<a href='#'>".$terms."</a>";
    }  

    return $terms;
}
}
```

Comment: i get a syntax error on this line `terms ="<a href='#'>".term."</a>"`

Comment: i think your still missing a `$` from the beginning of`terms`?

Comment: i added the `$` to both `terms` and `term` and the syntax error has gone but the tags aren't displaying.

Comment: sorry.. I was added without $ and ; etc .please just compile now .

Comment: sorry but still doesn't work. nothing displaying at all

Comment: just use `echo` statement .

Comment: i have, i used `<?php echo my_post_terms(); ?>`, no work still

Comment: add `echo "<a href='#'>".$terms."</a>";`

Comment: oh wait... it kinda works but without the links, so its still a string

Comment: the `echo "<a href='#'>".$terms."</a>";` is already in the function